# What happens to my website ranking if I take it down from my host and move it to another?

Tags: seo, wordpress

I have a website built on VistaPrint. It doesnt look good and I would like to move it to wordpress with new designs and functions. My website is currently on the top page when I search for it on google. My question is what would happen to the SEO if i do this? Will it take a hit? If so, how would I avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

If you can keep all of your content and URLs when moving the site, then you should maintain your rankings assuming that your user experience(UX) and webhosting speed improves in the process. In fact, you'll probably actually get a slight ranking boost because of it.

If on the other hand you have to delete all of your current content in order to achieve the move, then this is really risky. If those URLs and content are currently indexed and receiving traffic, you'll lose all of it if you delete it. On top of that, if Google is sending traffic to those pages, it means that Google has trust towards your domain. If you delete all of those pages, you're going to lose some of that trust as well.

I can tell you that I once deleted an old platform that was getting some traffic from Google, and I put up a new platform with entirely new content on the domain. Google ate up it up and began sending me substantially more traffic because of the new platform that I went with.

It's a big gamble to delete all of your old content. It might work, but just know that there's enormous risks associated with it. It would be much better if you can backup all of the old content and move it onto the new host.

Comment: Thank you. When you said "contents", what falls into this? Is it the website headings and titles and such?

Comment: You'll want to keep whatever content you can from all of the pages to maintain their rankings, especially the most important content. This is primarily the url, title, meta tags, headers, articles, text, images, videos and other media of the page.

Comment: Thank you. Would it matter if the contents stayed the same but at different urls? for example, I have everything in one single page right now and it is messy. I want build a separate contact page and about page. So when I am creating my contact and about pages, keeping the contents from my current contact and about pages on my new pages will help right?

Comment: You can change your contact and about us pages to new URLs if you want. But it's better if you 301 redirect the previous URLs to the new ones. You don't want to leave any old URLs as a 404 if possible.